Why does this host behave so oddly?
I try to save http://services.confetti.events/ into Wayback Machine but it refuses with an error message "Cannot resolve host services.confetti.events.". Ok, so I try
% host services.confetti.events

No response at all???
BUT - in my browser (Firefox on Mac) a web page appear when entering this address.
What is going on here?

Some local (i.e. on your device/network) DNS/hosts issue I would suspect, as services.confetti.events definitely does not exist

@JaromandaX services.confetti.events definitely DOES exist, although it seems to be an invite only site.

@BobGoddard ahh, so you have to mess with your DNS to access it - that is unusual

I am making no such comment. The address IS available in the DNS as normal. How you or @JaromandaX cannot resolve it, I do not know. Perhaps it is rejecting requests based on locale.

@BobGoddard - good point - service.confetti.events is resolved though

it'd be odd if the wayback machine and I had the same issue resolving an existing domain though
